# How to program the below text format logic in ruby to validate a text field

Tags: ruby, text, logic

I have a text field where it accepts only the text that satisfies the below criteria:

Text format of the below type where 'A' can be any random alphabets, 'D' is any numerical digit, but last digit is sum of all other digits modulo 10.

```
AAD-AAA-DDD
```

for example:

```
KN3-MNO-41_, this means the last digit is: 3 + 4 + 1 = 8, so it becomes: KN3-MNO-418
HK5-SFO-32_, this means the last digit is: 5 + 3 + 2 = 10, so it becomes HK5-SFO-320
```

I am in my intial learning of ruby, please help me: so how do I include these checks in the script and validate that the input text meets the criteria.

Thanks

Comment: If your form's field only accepts certain criteria, why not validate it in the browser using JavaScript before it gets submitted and the server has to validate it? Imagine if your system was popular and 1,000,000 people were all submitting that form per second. Does it make more sense to have your server try to process 1,000,000 validations/second, or their browser do one? Even if you revalidate on the server, having the browser do the trapping of bad entries is still going to reduce the load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
def valid?(w)
   w.match(/^[a-z][a-z]\d-[a-z][a-z][a-z]-\d\d\d$/i) and
   ([2,8,9].sum {|i| w[i].to_i} % 10 == w[10].to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wild whack at it:

```
REGEX = /^([a-z]{2})(\d)-([a-z]{3})-(\d)(\d)(\d)$/i
STRINGS = %w[
  KN3-MNO-418
  HK5-SFO-320
  KN3-MNO-419
  HK5-SFO-321
]

def valid?(str)
  chars1, d1, chars2, d2, d3, chksum = REGEX.match(str).captures
  ([d1, d2, d3].map(&:to_i).inject(:+) % 10) == chksum.to_i
end

STRINGS.each do |s|
  puts valid?(s)
end
```

Running that outputs:

```
true
true
false
false
```

For fun and profit you can change the `match` assignment to:

```
_, d1, _, d2, d3, chksum = REGEX.match(str).captures
```

and/or the calculation to:

```
([d1, d2, d3].inject(0) { |m, s| m += s.to_i } % 10) == chksum.to_i
```

Now, that's sure to be as bewildering to you as it is to me, so I'll break it down:

- `/^([a-z]{2})(\d)-([a-z]{3})-(\d)(\d)(\d)$/i` means:

  1. Start at the beginning of the string and find two characters between "a".."z", followed by...
  2. A single digit, followed by...
  3. A hyphen, followed by...
  4. Three characters between "a".."z", followed by another hyphen and...
  5. Two separate digits and the checksum digit.
- `REGEX.match(str).captures` matches the pattern to the string. `captures` returns an array of captured values from the string. "captures" are the parts in the pattern between parenthesis.
- The results of `captures` is assigned to the local variables in parallel. Sweet.
- `([d1, d2, d3].map(&:to_i).inject(:+) % 10) == chksum.to_i` is the part that makes us go "wheeeee!!!":

  1. `[d1, d2, d3].map(&:to_i)` converts an array of strings to an array of integers...
  2. `inject(:+)` is Ruby magic for "add all the elements of the array together."...
  3. `% 10` is `modulo 10`. Look up modolo, it's your new friend.
  4. The rest you can figure out.